# Проблема с Update в Entity Framework в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc

Почему не происходит изменение в бд при вызове context.SaveChanges() ?

```
    public ViewResult Edit(int productId) { // тут делается выборка из БД
       Product product = repository.Products
       .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
       product.ProductID = product.ProductID;
       return View(product);  // передается в представление в котором он
                // будет изменен, и будет вызвано действие по submit (HttpPost)  
       }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Product product) {
       if(ModelState.IsValid) {
          repository.SaveProduct(product); // update
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
       else {
          return View(product);
       }
    }

    ...
    EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IQueryable<Product> Products {
        get{ return context.Products;}
    }

    public void SaveProduct(Product product) {
        if (product.ProductID == 0) {
            context.Products.Add(product);
        }

        **context.SaveChanges();**  // почему то не происходит никаких изменений
    }
    ...
```

Comment: меня беспокоят 2 строчки:

    product.ProductID = product.ProductID; // что это?
    ...
    if (product.ProductID == 0) { // возможно при сохранении условие не выполняется

Comment: product.ProductID = product.ProductID; // что это?
ой, это я случайно вставил, этот код можно игнорировать так как ничего не делает(это я эксперементировал меняя свойства вручную)

if (product.ProductID == 0) - это условие для добавление новых продуктов, если ID = 0 в даном случае ID != 0. При отладке context.SaveChanges() просто не вызывает никаких SQL запросов для изменения БД

Comment: то есть 2 запроса к бд вместо одного?
а насчет "if (product.ProductID == 0)", можно сделать расширение для контекста на проверку новая запись или нет, чем дублировать код, что то такое в результате:
if(context.ModelName.NewRecord) ...

Comment: хотя, даже условие вынести из контроллера нужно, чтоб контроллер не раздувать, толстой то модель должна быть

Comment: да автор кода вообще не я, это из книги "Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework S. Sanderson, A. Freeman". Я вообще начинающий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась повторной выборкой продукта из бд и изменением всех его свойств в соответствий с тем продуктом, что в параметре. После этого SaveChanges() сработало.